# Finding a distance so that this function is a contraction mapping

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence, contraction-mapping

Let $f(x,y)=(y,\frac{2}{x+y})$ defined on $(0,\infty)\times (0,\infty)$. Is there a distance $d$ on $(0,\infty)\times (0,\infty)$ such that $f$ is a contraction of the metric space $((0,\infty)\times (0,\infty), d)$, namely there exists $0<\lambda<1$ such that
$$d(f(x,y),f(x',y')) \leqslant d((x,y),(x',y'))$$
for all $(x,y),(x',y')\in (0,\infty)\times (0,\infty)$.

I bet the answer is yes because one can prove that the order two recursive sequences defined by $f$ converge to $1$.

This question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4477147/find-the-metric-so-that-this-map-is-a-contraction) and remains unanswered.

Comment: Your function is nonexpansive with respect to Thompson's metric on $\mathbb{R}^2_{>0} := \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x_i > 0 \text{ for all } i \}$.  Thompson's metric on $\mathbb{R}^n_{>0}$ is $d_T(x,y) = \| \log(x) - \log(y) \|_\infty$ where $\log$ is the entrywise natural logarithm and $\| \cdot \|_\infty$ is the maximum norm.

Comment: It is not a contraction with respect to Thompson's metric, however.  The function $f$ is a composition of the linear function defined by the matrix $M = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ \tfrac{1}{2} & \tfrac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}$ with the nonlinear map $J(x_1,x_2) = (x_1, x_2^{-1})$.  Both $M$ and $J$ are nonexpansive with respect to Thompson's metric.  In fact, $J$ is a Thompson's metric isometry.  However, $f$ does not reduce the distance between $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$, for example.

Comment: Thank you @BrianLins, even if it does not solve the question it's still something! 
I remember that this question has been already asked but I suspect it was deleted since I'm not able to find the original thread nor the proof: it might involve some arctan functions in the distance, but I'm not sure.